# Set first scene based on platform?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So basically I would like to load FIRST scene based on a certain platform. I have two Main Menu scenes, each meant for certain platform.

I could do this in build settings when exporting my game (I could just uncheck the scene(ex: iOS) I don't need, and then the other scene will load (ex Android) (if its the next in row), but I would like to do that programatically, so I don't accidentally upload binary meant for iOS on Android or vice versa.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this?

```
void Start() {
    #if UNITY_IOS
        Application.LoadLevel("IOS_SCENE");
    #endif
    #if UNITY_ANDROID
        Application.LoadLevel("ANDROID_SCENE");
    #endif
}
```

You can find more directives [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html)

Answer (score 2):

Usually, anything platform dependent for build is done in:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Callbacks.PostProcessBuildAttribute.html

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BuildPlayerPipeline.html

Answer (score 0):

you have to use this https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html
So basically create a script that runs first (choose any way you want) , then create separate code for each directive in the same script and it will decide which code to run based on platform